# Converter with TextWatchers and EditText

Tags: android, android-studio, textwatcher

I'm trying to create a small converter with multiple `TextWatcher`s and `EditText`s, example:

```
m: enter value /m space

km: enter value //km space
```

When  you introduce a value, for example  2000 meters (in the meters space), you will see in the km space 2km. This is my code:

```
etm.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            double m=0, cmetres;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");
            if(etm.hasFocus()) {
                String et1c = s.toString();


                if ("R$0,00".equals(s.toString())){

               longkm = 0;

                etkm.setText("" + df.format(longkm));


                } else {
                    if (et1c.equals("")) {
                        cmetres = 1;

                    } else {
                        m = Double.parseDouble(et1c);
                        cmetres = 0;
                    }

                    if ((cmetres == 0)) {


                       //CONVERSION CODE

                        etkm.setText("" + df.format(longkm));
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    etkm .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            double km = 0, ckm;

            DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("#.########");

            if (etkm.hasFocus()) {
                String et2c = s.toString();


                if ("R$0.00".equals(s.toString())) {

                  longm=0;


                    etm.setText("" + df1.format(longm));

                } else {
                    if (et2c.equals("")) {

                        ckm = 1;
                    } else {
                        km = Double.parseDouble(et2c);
                        ckm = 0;
                    }

                    if (ckm == 0) {
                        //conversion code
                        etm.setText("" + df1.format(longmk));

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is that this code works perfectly on the emulator but the app crash on my phone when I delete some decimal, for example : 1,11 or 0.0001 etc...
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post some example of what you enter and  when the app crashes ?

Comment: yes, the app crah when I try to change a decimal value on the phone for example 1,1km, 0,01, m. So if i put 1100 m I will see in the km space 1,1km and if I want to change the Km this 1,1 km the app  crash. But this not happens with exact values, exmaple: 2200, 10000, 1, 33, with exact values the app works good on the phone.My app works good on  the emulator and I don't understand why I have problems on the phone. Thank you

Comment: Paste the crash logs please.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.jvh01jesusgmail.multioperator, PID: 32188
                                                                                   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "0,"

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ","`, its not a part of number format and you can not enter text also.

**Solution :**

```
<EditText
    ......
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
```

which allows you to enter only valid numbers/characters, which allowed to use to define valid number.

Comment: yeah, I have the android:inputType="numberDecimal" in my Eddit Texts, but don't works on the phone, only works on the emulator, this is my  crash log: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.jvh01jesusgmail.multioperator, PID: 32188 java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "0,"

Comment: well.. EditText is not allowing me to enter **`,`**.. What is your `Locale` or Currency

Comment: Oh, I just saw what is the difference beetween phone and emulator, in the emulator decimal numbers appears witch  " . " as 1.1 2.45, 0.11, but on my phone appears with " , "as 1,1, 2,45, 0,45. But I don't know how to change this.  My Currency is euro and my locale spain. Thank you

Comment: try this `df.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN));`

Comment: if that didnt work then replace **`,`** with **`.`** before formatting to double

Comment: This code give me this error :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ISO 3166 country,                                                                         If I put DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,#####"); with the " , "I saw in my phone the correct numbers 1.11, 0.234 (with " . ")but the problem is when I have for example 3meters the app should show 0.003 km but appears 0. The other works well.

Comment: And with the last code crahs when I have for example 58.993.495 and I try to delete somo number java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "532.88714.5699

Answer (score 0):

Okey I solve it with this code:

```
 DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
            DecimalFormatSymbols sym = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
            sym.setDecimalSeparator('.');
            df1.setDecimalFormatSymbols(sym);
```

Thank you everybody! good day!